# On entry save... redirecting tp front-end homepage

Tags: matrix, assets

Currently have a channel entry that has amongst one of its fields a MATRIX to upload a series of images too. Now this is currently been populated using the MATRIX MULTI UPLOAD and for the most part is working well.

Just recently the client has seen that when adding over 100 images to this matrix on submitting the entry the page is showing the homepage of the site under the Control Panel URL and is not saving the data.

Ive upped things such as :

upload_max_filesize = 100M
post_max_size = 120M
memory_limit = 100M
max_execution_time = 900
max_file_uploads = 300
max_input_time = 500

But this doesn't seem to have been much help. The figures are correct still, but its just an odd scenario. Anyone else has a similar issue with even showing the actual homepage under a control panel URL.

Also any other ideas as to what could be causing this?

Cheers
B.

Comment: It sounds like it could have something to do with the server settings for uploading restrictions. Just because you increase the upload limit doesn't necessarily mean that your server will allow you to increase it. Have you asked your host about this?